# Merge Mongoose results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Query result:

```
[ { _id: 523ab1be60239c8120000001,
    posts: 
     [ { _id: 523ab1be60239c8120000002,
         creator: 523ab1be60239c8120000001,
         listingType: 'lease',
         title: 'My Second Listing - Made By Person 1',
         __v: 0 } ] },
  { _id: 523ab1e224bfaea520000001,
    posts: 
     [ { _id: 523ab1e224bfaea520000002,
         creator: 523ab1e224bfaea520000001,
         listingType: 'lease',
         title: 'My Second Listing - Made By Person 2',
         __v: 0 },
       { _id: 523ab865ae55497d27000001,
         creator: 523ab1e224bfaea520000001,
         listingType: 'free',
         title: 'My Third Listing - Made By Person 2',
         __v: 0 } ] } ]
```

I want to be able to store all `posts` in one array or object so that I can sort them by their `_id` (timestamp) and display them to the user much easier.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm thinking about doing a loop on each posts and execute a sorting algorithm of some sort to achieve this but just by the word "loop", it already sounds inefficient.

Comment: You could sort them on the server (in MongoDB), or do it locally. There's not much magic to sorting on the client, code will need to visit every post, via a loop or some other technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to sort the documents themselves, I would say to use MongoDB's sort() function.  However, since you want to extract a part of the documents, combine them into one object, and sort, there are a few options, and I'm not sure which will perform best.

If you keep your query the way it is, then you really only have the choice of sorting on the application side using a loop of some sort.

Probably, the cleanest way to do this would be to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).  Depending on what your original query was, you can probably transform it into a `$match` operation and use it first in your pipeline.  Then, you should be able to `$unwind` the 'posts' array, `$sort` by timestamp, and `$group` them back together into a single array.